# Data extraction to a figure output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract the bus voltage from a text file, then plot it into a figure,
the text looks like this

```
Bus Voltage: 3.300 V
Bus Current: -1.805 mA
Power: 5.610 mW
Shunt voltage: -0.170 mV 


Bus Voltage: 3.316 V
Bus Current: -1.695 mA
Power: 6.098 mW
Shunt voltage: -0.180 mV
```

and the used code to extract and plot it, the below is what I think should be changed

```
x=numpy.array([])
with open(fileS) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    for line in lines :
        if line.startswith("Bus Voltage") :
            x=np.append(x,line.split()[2])
ax.plot(t, x, c='r', label='Volt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```py
text_data = """Bus Voltage: 3.300 V
Bus Current: -1.805 mA
Power: 5.610 mW
Shunt voltage: -0.170 mV 


Bus Voltage: 3.316 V
Bus Current: -1.695 mA
Power: 6.098 mW
Shunt voltage: -0.180 mV"""

data = [line.strip().split(": ") for line in text_data.splitlines() if len(line.strip()) > 0]

bus_voltages = [line[1] for line in data if line[0].lower() == "bus voltage"]
```

Comment: thanks ! Note: my posted code works too with numpy library